# Patch object Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to create a patch object using VBscript ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370594(v=vs.85).aspx)) and be able to read properties from `*.msp` file which is not installed.

When I do this

```
Dim objPatch
Set objPatch = Wscript.CreateObject ("WindowsInstaller.Installer.Patch")
```

I get the following :

```
>> Error:   Could not locate automation class named "WindowsInstaller.Installer.Patch".
```